# Adding swingNode to javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, swingutilities

i wrote an app with javaFx and wanna add a JButton to a Pane in SwingNode
this is my controller of fxml

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Pane pane;

    private static final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        createSwingContent(swingNode);
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JButton jButton = new JButton("Click me!");
            jButton.setBounds(0,0,80,50);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            panel.add(jButton);

            swingNode.setContent(panel);

        });
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, so what's wrong whit it ? 
BTW, when i added a non-swingNode to my Pane it works and shows the Button but
in swingNode manner it doesn't work !

Comment: Might not make any difference, but why is `swingNode` static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are managing all the layout "by hand", by calling `setLayout(null)` and `setBounds(...);` on the button, you need to size the panel by hand too:

```
private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JButton jButton = new JButton("Click me!");
        jButton.setBounds(0,0,80,50);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(jButton);

        panel.setSize(90, 60);

        swingNode.setContent(panel);

    });
}
```

Alternatively, use a layout manager (e.g., just the default one, as shown here):

```
private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JButton jButton = new JButton("Click me!");
        // jButton.setBounds(0,0,80,50);

        jButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 50));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        // panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(jButton);

        swingNode.setContent(panel);

    });
}
```

With your current code, the button is added to the `JPanel`, but since the `JPanel` has zero width and height, so does the `SwingNode`, and so you can't see the button.

As an aside, it is a mistake to make the `swingNode` static. If you were to load the FXML more than once in the application, you would have the same node at two different places in the scene graph, which is not allowed.